# window.history.go(-1) not work in firefox?

Tags: javascript

I just use window.history.go(-1) to return previous page in firefox, it won't work if the script in a iframe, it works fine in ie , opera and chrome. can somebody tell me why?

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

are you asking about accessing the history node of an Iframe

OR

you want to parent's history FROM an iframe

Comment: @teneff,I want access the history node of iframe, not his parent.

Answer (score -1):

I did tried

```
window.history.go(-1)
```

in Firefox 3.6.8 and it did worked for the iframe ... try creating a simple html page to test if it's working for youur version of FF (I'm quite sure it will work), so maybe the problem is somewhere else

Comment: This should be a comment, as it doesn't answer the question.